# How to import contacts from Samsung E1170?

Tags: usb, contacts, import

I have a [Samsung E1170 mobile phone](http://www.samsung.com/uk/consumer/mobile-devices/mobile-phones/bar/GT-E1170ZKAXEU) and a USB datacable for it.

1. How can I import/copy the contacts from the phone to my computer?
2. Is there any application for Mac which can do that?
3. If not, how can I do that at all in principle?

([Question on Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/356443/import-contacts-from-samsung-e1170).)

Comment: Is that an Android based phone? Are your contacts linked to gmail by any chance?

Comment: @ckpepper02: No. I linked it.

Answer (score 1):

Before 10.7 Mac OS included an application called iSync for exactly that. If you're still running Snow Leopard or lower you might want to look for an iSync plugin for your phone.

Comment: I have 10.7 ...

Comment: I just was able to get iSync (from a 10.6 DVD) but I figured out that iSync does not support the Samsung E1170.